# Quartz performance is so slow when I used JDBC persistence

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz-persistence

I'm using spring-boot-starter-quartz dependency and using JDBC persistence but the performance using Scheduler.scheduleJob() method is so slow, I did a couple of tests with Jmeter and I got 70 transactions per second but if I don’t use JDBC persistence I got over 800 transactions per seconds.

Anyone know how can I improve the performance for quart using JDBC persistance?

Nota: this is my application.yaml to quartz and using mybatis and SQL_SERVER

```
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties.org.quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceName: QuartzScheduler
            makeSchedulerThreadDaemon: true
            instanceId : AUTO
            batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount: 1
            batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow: 0
          threadPool:
            class : org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
            threadCount : 10
          jobStore:
            class : org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass : org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
            isClustered : true
            clusterCheckinInterval : 20000
            acquireTriggersWithinLock: false
```